# is there a button function to completely remove background?

Tags: javascript, html, button, background

I'm having trouble with a button function. I have an HTML document with a background set for all pages (in order to keep a common theme). I created a button on one of my pages with the intent of removing the background on that one specific page. I used a script function to change the background color to white. When I press the button, the background changes to white, except for the parts that have text (see images linked below). How can I get the button to essentially remove the entire background?

[before button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnRxs.jpg)

[after button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3tfR.png)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <body>
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url(IMG_7305.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
</style>


<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Press here to remove the background image </button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("about").style.backgroundColor = "white"
  }
</script>
<p> 
  I want the background to be cleared... even here!!
</p>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far @johnosterman

Comment: i will update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the body where the image is, not just the "about" element.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/beach-quotes-1559667853.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Press here to remove the background image </button>

<p> 
  I want the background to be cleared... even here!!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your background image on the body tag in the css, you can give it to a class and remove the class when clicked.

```
 <body class='background'>
<style>
  .background {
    background-image: url(IMG_7305.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
</style>


<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Press here to remove the background image </button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.body.classList.remove('background')
  }
</script>
<p> 
  I want the background to be cleared... even here!!
</p>
```

I would also recommend adding a container and style that rather than the body tag itself.